# List of Lists for sending paths from client to server?

Tags: unity, c#, networking, unity-networking

I have a client server scenario and I'm looking into distributed AI. I want the server to move x amount of ai characters around a map by pathfinding and then send the x amount of paths to the client which will apply each path to its corresponding AI character. This is for research purposes to see if this approach, by sending the new path of each server AI to the client AI for it to follow, is better than constantly sending a positional update across a network everytime a server gameobject moves slightly. I would like this X amount to range anywhere from 10 to 2000, a big ask i know, but i'll go into what I have atm.

Atm I have this working for 2 AI characters and it can be expanded, but with my existing code it would mean an awful lot of copying and pasting! So on the server when the path is created it is sent to a script which can bundle it into an RPC an send it on its way:

```
public class GrabbingArrayFromUnitScript : NetworkBehaviour {

public List<Vector3> receivedArrays = new List<Vector3>(); 
public List<Vector3> receivedArrays1 = new List<Vector3>(); 


    [ClientRpc]
    void RpcPosFromServerToGoTo(Vector3 [] path, String name)
    {

    if (name == "SeekerPrefab") 
    {
        receivedArrays.AddRange (path);
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log ("Received");
    }
    if (name == "SeekerPrefab (1)") 
    {
        receivedArrays1.AddRange (path);
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log ("Received 1");
    }



    }

public void PrintPath(Vector3 [] path)
{
    if (isServer) 
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Send Array ...");
        RpcPosFromServerToGoTo (path, transform.name);
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Sent!!");



    } 
}

}
```

So as you can see from the above if I wanted to add more AI characters in I would have to add more if statements to the RPC call, and if I wanted 2000 AI in that would be alot of copying. So what could I do here to reduce this code down? Would I use a list of lists? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This seems more like a programming problem then a game development problem. Use a Dictionary<name,SearchContext> where the name is the key like 'SeekerPrefab' and the SearchContext is a class you create with all the details of the search. Then you can use the dictionary to lookup by key: searches[ 'SeekerPrefab' ]

Comment: As a side note, I think i can be proven that sending only the paths instead of the positional data is cheaper from a bandwidth perspective. However, in your example you are sending *all* the data at once instead of a vector every few frames as you would in sending position updates. That might be a killer if you burst that much data for many entities at once. You might want to consider a system where you send N points of a path at a time, throttled by a bandwidth limiter on the server.

Comment: @Steven ty for comments and answer! A dictionary is something ive never used before but must look into, i'll post what i managed to do below. But yea as you say it can be proven, thats the aim :) see im not sure if I didnt explain properly or maybe I have done the wrong thing entirely, but with my code i am sending a complete path to a point when it is calculated, and only when the server has followed and needs a new path will another be sent along the network to the client, so what do you mean by sending all the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is what I have managed to throw together, time is of the essence and tbh dictionaries confuse me, they are probs more efficient, but this will do for now:

```
public class AiManager : NetworkBehaviour {


ClientAiMoveToPosArray clientAiMoveToPosArray;



[ClientRpc]
void RpcPosFromServerToGoTo(Vector3 [] path, String name)
{   

    clientAiMoveToPosArray = GameObject.Find (name).GetComponent<ClientAiMoveToPosArray> ();
    clientAiMoveToPosArray.receivedArrays.AddRange(path);


}

public void PrintPath(Vector3 [] path, String name)
{
    if (isServer) 
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Send Array ..." + name);
        RpcPosFromServerToGoTo (path, name);
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Sent!!");


    } 
}
}
```

Whenever I send the path to the RPC I also send the name, then when sending the RPC the name goes aswell. Reading in the RPC the object is tracked down by its name and then the script which reads the path is brought up and the path placed into it. Again I have been rushed for time. I will try a dictionary at a later time.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary to keep the entities and requests in them, and a SearchContext to hold the related data for one entity together:

```
class SearchContext
{
  List<Vector3> points;
};

public Dictionary<String, SearchContext> context = new Dictionary<String, SearchContext>();

[ClientRpc]
void RpcPosFromServerToGoTo(Vector3 [] path, String name)
{
    SearchContext context;
    // context doesn't exist yet - add it
    if ( contexts.TryGet( name, out context ) == false )
{
   context = new SearchContext;
   contexts[ name ] = context;
}

context.points.AddRange( path );
UnityEngine.Debug.Log ("Received");
}
```